# ROS Groovy vs. Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, update, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

is it possible to switch from Gazebo version which comes with Groovy (1.5) to the latest one installed from deb repo according to instructions on gazebosim.org? I mean switch in a way that I will be able to launch it using rosrun etc. I guess it will be necessary to somehow overlay simulator_gazebo, right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62696/ros-groovy-vs.-gazebo/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-14**:
@ZdenekM I am not entirely sure, but gazebosim website clearly specifies that gazebo via ROS and gazebo as a debian installation from gazebosim website are two different routes to working with gazebo -- so may be you can achieve your goal, but it sure will get messy !

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2014-07-02**:
@ZdenekM Apparently not, the gazebo which comes made into a ROS distro is strictly meant for that distro, on changing the version of gazebo you will face compilation problems and if it does compile, it may also not work with other utilities (read nodes) of ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gazebo developers prefer that questions like this be directed to http://answers.gazebosim.org

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1